# Insert liquid tag into js file

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to add `{{ product.variants.first.sku }}` into a js file, the function is below

```
function buildPrice(data, onSale, priceVaries) {
  var priceHtml = '',
    onSaleClass = onSale ? ' price--on-sale' : '';
  var productSku = "{{ product.variants.first.sku }}";
  priceHtml += '<dl class="price' + onSaleClass + '" data-price>';
  priceHtml += '<div class="price__vendor">';
  priceHtml += '<dt>';
  priceHtml += '<span class="visually-hidden">' + bcSfFilterConfig.label.vendor + '</span>';
  priceHtml += '</dt>';
  priceHtml += '<dd>';
  priceHtml += data.vendor;
  priceHtml += '</dd>';
  priceHtml += '</div>';
  priceHtml += '<div class="product__sku">';
  priceHtml += '<dd>';
  priceHtml += productSku;
  priceHtml += '</dd>';
  priceHtml += '</div>';
  priceHtml += '<div class="price__regular card-price">';
  priceHtml += '<dt>';
  priceHtml += '<span class="visually-hidden visually-hidden--inline">' + bcSfFilterConfig.label.regular_price + '</span>';
  priceHtml += '</dt>';
  priceHtml += '<dd>';
  priceHtml += '<span class="price-item price-item--regular" data-regular-price>';
```

As you can see I tried using `var productSku = "{{ product.variants.first.sku }}";` but it still just pastes `{{ product.variants.first.sku }}` in html instead of loading the sku number.

How can I get it to render the liquid insert instead of just pasting the code in visible html?

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing anything terribly dynamic in your sample-- there's nothing there that couldn't be done with a snippet of liquid.

However the way I go about blending shopify's info with javascript is like:

`pricesnippet.liquid`

```
<script>
var myObj = {
product: {{product |json}},
startingVariant : {{product.selected_or_first_available_variant | json }}
};

// now do something with product:
(function(){
    myObj.product....

})();
</script>
```

and then

`{% include 'pricesnippet' %}` in your liquid where needed.

Comment: Aye: If you remember that asset files need to be strongly cacheable, it's easier to remember that variables that change depending on the page or the user's actions (such as `product`, `collection` and `cart`) cannot be used inside of an asset file.  Setting up your code and passing in the appropriate values like this is exactly the best route to go. :)

Comment: Awesome I'll give this a go when I can, I'm modifying an app's js file which is why it's posting html through javascript, i have no idea why it's doing that either and why it isn't just a snippet in liquid. will let you know if it works!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need the json filter.

```
product.variants.first.sku
```

That is a value. Makes no sense to filter it as json.

Comment: I tried that first and it doesn't work, 'priceHtml += product.variants.first.sku;'

Comment: Obviously, you need to surround the liquid in {{ }} filters and ensure you use the .js.liquid extension to ensure the js file is parsed with liquid too.

Comment: Also, modern Javascript now supports templating, and so you can skip all the ugly string building and use templates. Far easier, less buggy, just better.

Comment: Yes, the `json` filter would be appropriate as it also escapes values to be javascript-legal.  A blank SKU would thus become `null`, and a SKU that included weird characters would have them escaped for you (so a product with a sku `WIDGET-2"` would not break your javascript file).  However, also at issue is the fact that `product` is not something that an asset file can access, as asset files cannot access any liquid variables that are even remotely dynamic - they can access `settings` and use the `| t` filter, but not a lot else. :)